# Use ST_Buffer with a conditional distance based on an attribute

Tags: postgis, buffer, syntax

I am quite new to postgres/postgis and are still learning basic skills.
I have imported a pointlayer shapefile into my postgres database.

I need to make a buffer of varying radius around the points depending on attribute. 
I have been reading about the ST_buffer function in the documentation but I am having problems to interpreting it so far.

I am trying to use
SELECT 
geometry ST_Buffer(geometry g1, float radius_of_buffer);

I have tried
SELECT geometry ST(mypoints.geom, 100)
FROM
myschema.mypoints

I hope someone could help me to write it out properly

Best Regards

Comment: SELECT ST_Buffer(geom, 100) FROM myschema.mypoints

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a conditional buffering based on some attribute, you can use a [case statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-conditional.html), eg,

```
SELECT ST_Buffer(geom, CASE WHEN atr = 0 then 10 WHEN atr=1 THEN 20 ELSE 30 END) 
FROM mypoints;
```

Obviously, you can have as many WHENs as you like, though it could get cumbersome fast. If it is a straight multiplier, then you can just do `ST_Buffer(geom, atr * 2)`, for example.

Comment: Thank you! <br/>
I think I will use views and create one view for each attribute that need another buffer size. I have about 10 different attributes that need their own buffer size.

Comment: Great. If it has helped, please accept. I have edited your question to, I hope, better reflect what you are asking. Please re-edit if you disagree with me.

Comment: Can you use conditional buffering based on attribute from a different table? <br/>

Comment: Yes, assuming you can join it somehow to the first table?

Comment: Wow, that was a super fast reply! I went to edit my question bc I accidentally posted it before it was done =)
I have created a view in my postgres db. I want the user to be able to put in any value in a column that the buffer radius will be generated from. In that way will the buffer be generated on the fly

Comment: Accidentally posted a week ago, lol. I'm not sure I totally follow what you mean by put in any value in a column -- which column? It is probably cleaner to ask another question, but I am happy to try and help you get the answer if it is just a minor change to this question.

Comment: I hope my try to create the querry I am looking for will explain my aim
SELECT 
  event_point.id, address.street
  st_buffer(event_punkt.geom, 100) AS "Buffer"
   FROM event_point, address
   WHERE ST_contains("Buffer", address.geom);

e.g I am trying to use the buffer to select values from another table in the same schema using intersect. I am happy to ask a new question if you think it is a big change from the original question.

Comment: You are probably better off using ST_DWithin for this, as it will use the index better than buffering. What about the conditional statement, or was that just this question?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I had too many ideas in my mind and got them confused. I should probably ask another question. Thanks again